# Deploy spring boot applications

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I know spring boot applications can be deployed to production environments as war files. But what is the typical way of deploying spring boot applications? Does it only require a jvm, not a container?

Answer (score 2):

The [Spring Boot Project Page](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) states that *Spring Boot makes it easy to create stand-alone, production-grade Spring based Applications that you can "just run"*.

Means by default, the [Spring Boot maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) or gradle plugin builds self-contained [executable](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html) jars, that contain all dependencies and an embedded webserver, e.g. tomcat or jetty. The [Spring Boot Getting Started](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html) doc gives you an introduction to that. Using this approach you just need a JVM to run your application. But you can also configure it to create war files if this is a better fit to your production environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers.

Comment: Does that mean i can do a
mvn install
And run this using a java command in a jvm?

Comment: Yes, have a look at the end of the [Spring Boot Getting Started](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html#getting-started-first-application-executable-jar): The executable jar created by the maven spring boot plugin is then started with `java -jar target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Answer (score 1):

**Does it only require a jvm, not a container?**

It can run anywhere Java is setup.

Spring Boot's use of embedded containers and why Spring chose to go the container-less route. Many of their main driving forces were ease of use while testing and debugging, and being able to deploy Spring-based Java applications to the cloud, or any other environment.

Rest can be found out in attached image.

[image: Answer to your question]

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot applications if they are serving web requests do require a container. You can either deploy them as a war inside a container such as tomcat/jetty. Or you can deploy them with embedded container, tomcat.